# Select input is not showing value when using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Im trying material ui select but it is not working as i would like to. it is not showing the default value when i use the map function but it does when using the traditional way.

*** The way which is working ***

```
<Select
              id="standard-select-categories"
              defaultValue="UK"
              label="Select Country"
              name="country"
              select
              variant="standard"
            >
             <MenuItem value="USA">
                USA
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="UK">
               UK
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Japon">
               Japon
              </MenuItem>

            </Select>
```

input shows UK as the selected country by default

*** The way which is NOT working ***

```
<Select
              id="standard-select-categories"
              defaultValue="UK"
              label="Select Country"
              name="country"
              select
              variant="standard"
            >

              {Countries_Flags.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem 
                key={option.name}
                value={option.name}
                >
                  {<img src={option.flag} alt={option.name} className="select-country-items" />}
                  {option.name}

                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
```

input doesnt show UK as the selected country by default

Comment: The code looks fine. Just double check the Countries_Flags array to make sure that there is a value that matches "UK" exactly. for example : not "U.K." or "Uk "

Comment: It is. I tried with another countries like Venezuela and still not working.

Comment: Could you throw it into a codesandbox? It works for me : https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-tu-955zch?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Take a look my friend. It isnt working for me https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-butterfly-s6wjj9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's working. The default value you're providing does not match the name. Eg: the name for UK is actually "United Kingdom" . Take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-night-j93rbi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes! I saw what i was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value being assigned to the MenuItem needs to match the value you set for the defaultValue prop on the select.

eg: [{name:"United Kingdom"}] . "United Kingdom" should be the defaultValue

```
        <Select
          id="standard-select-categories"
          defaultValue="United Kingdom"
          label="Select Country"
          name="country"
          select
          variant="standard"
        >
          // "United Kindom" for the defaultValue prop
          <MenuItem value={"United Kindom"}>UK</MenuItem>
          // "United States of America" for the defaultValue prop
          <MenuItem value={"United States of America"}>USA</MenuItem>
        </Select>
```

Comment: Working Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-night-j93rbi?file=/src/App.js . I would suggest using the isoCode as the value but that's just a personal preference since there is less chance of spelling errors.